# Can't launch server-side of maven web application with websockets

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jakarta-ee, websocket

I'm trying to connect to server-side via web-socket but connection is not being established. I use maven to build a project and launching with `mvn compile tomcat:run`
Tomcat logs folder into the project is empty.

JavaScript

```
var wsUri = "ws://localhost:8080/checkers/";
  var output;

  function init()
  {
    output = document.getElementById("messages");
    testWebSocket();
  }

  function testWebSocket()
  {
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);
    websocket.onopen = function(evt) { onOpen(evt); };
    websocket.onclose = function(evt) { onClose(evt); };
    websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { onMessage(evt); };
    websocket.onerror = function(evt) { onError(evt); };
  }

  function onOpen(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("CONNECTED");
    doSend("WebSocket rocks");
  }

  function onClose(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen("DISCONNECTED");
  }

  function onMessage(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: blue;">RESPONSE: ' + evt.data+'</span>');
    websocket.close();
  }

  function onError(evt)
  {
    writeToScreen('<span style="color: red;">ERROR:</span> ' + evt.data);
  }

  function doSend(message)
  {
    writeToScreen("SENT: " + message); 
    websocket.send(message);
  }

  function writeToScreen(message)
  {
    var pre = document.createElement("p");
    pre.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
    pre.innerHTML = message;
    output.appendChild(pre);
  }
```

ServerSide

```
@ServerEndpoint("/checkers")
public class CheckersApp {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ChekersApp.class);

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen() {
        System.out.println("Welcome", new Date);
        logger.log("Welcome", new Date);
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello websockets");  
    }

}
```

There is "ERROR: undefined" on the page.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by: "Tomcat logs folder into the project is empty" Does this mean the webapp folder is empty, or that there are no log statements regarding your application's deployment.

Comment: I looked at the webapps folder it is empty too. I mean `target/tomcat/logs` folder is empty. And it turns out that `target/tomcat/webapps` is empty too